# Add ShortCode field to Advanced Custom Fields plugin - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

I need to add a shortcode field to the Advanced Custom Fields plugin for Wordpress. I'm building a client's website and using the ACF plugin to create custom fields, after which I added the content of those fields to elements using Elementor to structure the page.

The customer uses an external sales platform that generates a code for him that adds a button to the website, allowing the purchase directly on the page with a popup:
https://cursosempsicologia.rodrigoremir.com/elementor-588/

I want to add a field to the ACF plugin that allows the customer to put this code directly in the creation of the new post, but none of the available fields works, when added to Elementor, it does not look like the example page, it just displays the code.

I want to be able to add a field so that the client puts the code and the code in turn is recognized by the elementor

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function importHotmart(){ 
        var imported = document.createElement('script'); 
        imported.src = 'https://static.hotmart.com/checkout/widget.min.js'; 
        document.head.appendChild(imported); 
        var link = document.createElement('link'); 
        link.rel = 'stylesheet'; 
        link.type = 'text/css'; 
        link.href = 'https://static.hotmart.com/css/hotmart-fb.min.css'; 
        document.head.appendChild(link);    } 
    importHotmart(); 
 </script> 
 <a onclick="return false;" href="https://pay.hotmart.com/O81031889V?checkoutMode=2&off=xjdoulx4" class="hotmart-fb hotmart__button-checkout">Comprar Agora</a>
```